# Vertx 3.4.2 receive a file using netSocket

Tags: java, vert.x

i'm trying to receive un file from a netSocketClient in vetrx 3.4.2, this is my code:

```
NetServerOptions options = new NetServerOptions().setPort(10000);
NetServer netserver = vertx.createNetServer(options);
netserver.connectHandler(sock -> {

    System.out.println("Incoming connection!");
    sock.handler(buffer-> {
       String dd = buffer.getString(0,buffer.length());
       System.out.println("new Buffer: "+dd);
       sock.write("From serveur: "+buffer.getString(0, buffer.length()));
    });

    sock.closeHandler(v -> {
       System.out.println("The socket has been closed");
    });
}).listen();
```

but i receive a decoped buffer.

my question is how i can get the end buffer of the file in a single buffer?

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it's working:

```
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
sock.handler(buffer-> {
    String dd = buffer.getString(0,buffer.length());
    if(dd.contains("EOT")){
      dd = dd.replace("EOT", "");
      buff.append(dd);
    }else{
      buff.append(dd);
    }
});
```